# What is the chemical equation for enthalpy of solution of hydrated salts?

Tags: enthalpy

If I take the anhydrous salt $\ce {CuSO_4}$, the equation for its dissolution in water would be:
$$ \ce {CuSO_4}_{(s)} + \ce {aq}.\rightarrow \ce {CuSO_4}_{(aq)}  $$

Now for the hydrated salt $\ce {{CuSO_4}\cdot {5H_2O}}_{(s)}$, is it this:
$$ \ce {{CuSO_4}\cdot {5H_2O}}_{(s)} + \ce {aq}.\rightarrow \ce {CuSO_4}_{(aq)}  $$

or is the output the "aqueous version" of the hydrated salt ($\ce {{CuSO_4}\cdot {5H_2O}}_{(aq)}$), if that's even a thing? I think it's the first one, but I don't understand why the salt would become anhydrous when dissolved.

Comment: Note that the current convention is not to write the compound state as a subscript. E.g $\ce{H2(g)}$ as `$\ce{H2(g)}$`

Comment: It is the first one. The salt does not become anhydrous when dissolved; quite the contrary, it becomes, er, dissolved. "CuSO4" in "CuSO4 (aq)" is not an indication of being anhydrous. Quite the contrary.

Comment: AVS should have written : $$\ce{CuSO4  + aq. ->  Cu^{2+} + SO4^{2-}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ce{CuSO4(aq)}$ is just a shortcut for $\ce{Cu^2+(aq) + SO4^2-(aq)}$.

$$\ce{CuSO4(s) ->[H2O]Cu^2+(aq) + SO4^2-(aq)}$$

$$\ce{CuSO4 . 5 H2O(s) ->[H2O]Cu^2+(aq) + SO4^2-(aq)}$$

As the symbol (aq) means implicitly involved, indefinite amount of ion-hydrating water, the reactions do not need to be enumerated wrt the water molecule count.

Crystal water abandons ions and becomes ordinary water, possibly but not necessarily taking first dibs in ion hydration.